# Control URL breaking

Tags: biblatex, url

Is there a way to control the url breaking with `biblatex`? I am using [ACS Guide](https://libguides.williams.edu/citing/acs) and it says:

> **Note:** Different web browsers break the text in different places of a URL. In a printed work, if the URL needs to be broken at the end of a line, the break should be made after a colon or a double slash; before a single slash, a tilde, a period, a comma, a hyphen, an underline, a question mark, a number sign, or a percent symbol; or before or after an equals sign or an ampersand.

I am also using the `url` package to typeset the url with the same font as my text. I read the package documentation and I am a bit confused by the macros `\UrlBreaks` and `\UrlBigBreaks`, butfrom what I gather these can only be used to allow a break after the listed characters, but not before as some of the requirements of the style guide (and I personally would not like breakings before a period for sure!). Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Maybe take a look at the `xurl` package.

Comment: @Bernard I just read the documentation and unless it's the wrong file, it just says that it is a package that tells the `url` package to allow a break. I am far from an expert but the style file defines the `\UrlBreaks` for all the characters, which means it defines breaks after the character, not before.

Comment: The command you are after is `\UrlSpecials`. You can control breaks before characters with this. I find it's usage a bit complicated though…

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think this should do what you want. It defines a new style `\urlstyle{acs}` which redefines `\UrlBreaks` and `\UrlSpecials` according to your rules.

There's one minor issue. It will prefer to break between `:` and `//` rather than between the `//`, but if you have `//` somewhere else, there is potential to break between. I tried to fix this, but couldn't make it work. I don't think this will occur in a real example though.

## MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{url}

\makeatletter
\def\url@acsstyle{%
  \def\UrlBreaks{\do\/}%
  \def\UrlSpecials{%
    \do\~{\penalty\UrlBreakPenalty\mathchar`~}%
    \do\.{\penalty\UrlBreakPenalty\mathchar`.}%
    \do\,{\penalty\UrlBreakPenalty\mathchar`,}%
    \do\-{\penalty\UrlBreakPenalty\mathchar`-}%
    \do\_{\penalty\UrlBreakPenalty\mathchar`_}%
    \do\?{\penalty\UrlBreakPenalty\mathchar`?}%
    \do\#{\penalty\UrlBreakPenalty\mathchar"23}%
    \do\%{\Url@percent}%
    \do\={\penalty\UrlBreakPenalty\mathchar`=\penalty\UrlBreakPenalty}%
    \do\&{\penalty\UrlBreakPenalty\mathchar`&\penalty\UrlBreakPenalty}%
    \do\ {\Url@space}\do\^^M{\Url@space}%
    \Url@force@Tilde}%
}
\makeatother

\raggedright

\begin{document}

\hsize 5cm

\section*{Default Style}

\url{https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/477945/control-url-breaking}

\section*{ACS Style}

\urlstyle{acs}

\url{https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/477945/control-url-breaking}

\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Comment: This definitely works in text. Any clue how to get `bibtex` to recognize these, though?

Comment: @ralk912 just put the code and the call to `\urlstyle` into your preamble after you load `biblatex` and it should just work.

Comment: Ah! Ended up finding that for some reason I had to use the style after `\begin{document}` (I was using it in the preamble as `\urlstyle{same}` and it did its job just fine). I just added the line `\def\UrlFont{}` to your code to get the desired font. Thanks!

Comment: @DavidPurton Nice solution....It suits my requirement too....Thanks a lot....

Answer (score 1):

You'll need three different packages, so include this in your code:

```
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{breakurl}
\usepackage[breaklinks]{hyperref}
```

Now, you'll just need to add `\def\UrlBreaks{\do\/\do-}` if you want to be able to break it after a `/` or a `-`.

For example, if the entry was this:

```
@misc{GartnerNFC,
author = "Clark, Sarah",
howpublished = "nfcworld.com",
month = aug,
note = "Cited July 3rd 2012",
title = "{Gartner’s Hype Cycle places NFC at ‘Peak of Inflated Expectations’}",
url = "http://www.nfcworld.com/2011/08/11/39008/gartner-hype-cycle-places-nfc-at-peak-of-inflated-expectations",
year = "2011"
}
```

It will look like this:

[image]

For other options, look into the `url` package documentation.

Comment: Maybe my question is not clear enough. I get how to indicate breaks after a character, but the style guide also indicates allowed breaks **before** a character, which unless I'm missing something, this won't do.